# SQL - AVG and Group by

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, average

I have the following table:

```
Date      |   Product   |   Price 
06-12-17  |    1.1      |   10
06-12-17  |    1.2      |   20
06-12-17  |    1.3      |   30
06-12-17  |    1.4      |   40
05-12-17  |    1.1      |   20
05-12-17  |    1.2      |   20
05-12-17  |    1.3      |   40
05-12-17  |    1.4      |   40
```

I am having hard time finding a query in SQL Server that can give me this result:

```
Date      |   Product |   Price 
06-12-17  |    1      |   25
05-12-17  |    1      |   30
```

I want the average price for each product everyday

Product starting from 1.1 to 24.4

Comment: Hint: `Group By`

Comment: What is the logic behind the product output all having values of `1`?

Comment: 1.1 = hour 1 and quarter 1
1.2 = hour 1 and quarter 2, 

I want the hourly average

Comment: Which sql db you are using?

Comment: I would consider fixing data model for your `Product` column.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you just need left part of `product`, `cast` to `int` and then aggregate using resultant value and `date`.

```
select date, 
       cast(product as int) as product, 
       avg(price) as Price
from table1
group by date, cast(product as int)
```

**Result:**

```
date        product Price
--------------------------
05-12-17    1       30
06-12-17    1       25
```

**[DEMO](http://rextester.com/GHIW74133)**

---

**Update:**

If product is of `varchar` datatype, use `cast` twice.

```
select date, 
       cast(cast(product as dec(3,1)) as int) as product, 
       avg(price) as Price
from table1
group by date, cast(cast(product as dec(3,1)) as int)
```

**[`Varchar()` Datatype DEMO](http://rextester.com/IMJN26961)**

Comment: I get the following error message "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '24,4' to data type int."

Comment: Ahan, so you column datatype is `varchar` which is sad. in that case, you need to cast it to `decimal` first and then to `int`. Check the updated answer in that case

Comment: With a nested cast?

Comment: Still getting this error message "Error converting data type varchar to numeric"

Comment: What is datatype for column `product`?

Comment: @Deldar22: I have added demo for varchar datatype as well. Hope this will helps :-)

Comment: The column 'Product' in the original table is VARCHAR(10), but I am putting the select statement into a view where the column 'Product' is dec(38,6). Putting your code in the view gives the same error message for some reason

Comment: @Deldar22: Its better to add all the information in the question. If the datatype is `dec(x,y)` left part can be extracted by casting to `int` and if datatype is `varchar`, it can be converted to `dec()` first and then to `int`. You can play around with the demos attached. Without your actual code, i am afraid that we can't proceed further..

Answer (score 2):

There depending on which number you want as output.
Like if

- `FLOOR()` of every number
- `cast(product as int)` convert to int

> Query:

```
 SELECT
  Date,
  FLOOR(product) product, // This function can be replaced with above according to the output
  AVG(price) price

FROM your_table
GROUP BY date, FLOOR(product) order by Date
```

As you say that output as the error you can also try the following.

```
 SELECT
  Date,
  FLOOR(convert(float, product)) product, // This function can be replaced by FLOOR(cast(product as float))
  AVG(price) price

FROM your_table
GROUP BY date, FLOOR(convert(float, product)) order by Date;
```

Comment: Getting the following "Error converting data type varchar to float"

Comment: although it's working on my system. if not you can try the updated code instead.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming every product value has a '.'(dot). Otherwise remove -1 from line 2.

```
SELECT Date,
   LEFT(CAST(product AS VARCHAR),charindex ('.',product) - 1),
   AVG(price)
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY Date, LEFT(CAST(product AS VARCHAR),charindex ('.',product) - 1);
```

Comment: It worked! Just have to change Group by to "Group by Date, LEFT(CAST(product AS VARCHAR), CHARINDES(',', product)-1)

Comment: Thanks. Corrected for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
     SELECT date,cast(product AS int) product,avg(Price) Price FROM (
     SELECT * FROM (VALUES 
     (cast('06-12-17' as date) ,    1.1      ,   10)
     ,(cast('06-12-17' as date) ,    1.2      ,   20)
     ,(cast('06-12-17' as date) ,    1.3      ,   30)
     ,(cast('06-12-17' as date) ,    1.4      ,   40)
     ,(cast('05-12-17' as date) ,    1.1      ,   20)
     ,(cast('05-12-17' as date) ,    1.2      ,   20)
     ,(cast('05-12-17' as date) ,    1.3      ,   40)
     ,(cast('05-12-17' as date) ,    1.4      ,   40)) a(Date      ,   
     Product   ,   Price ))x
     GROUP BY date,cast(product AS int)
```